# What punctuation should I use for "Can you imagine"?

Tags: punctuation

What punctuation should I use for "Can you imagine"?

> 1) And then, can you imagine, I saw a monkey in this tree!

or

> 2) And then... Can you imagine? I saw a monkey in this tree!

or

> 3) And then, can you imagine? I saw a monkey in this tree!

or

> 4) And then can you imagine I saw a monkey in this tree?

or

what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) And then, can you imagine, I saw a monkey in this tree!

This sentence is fine. Questions, if asked with the right inflection, do not need to end with a question mark. Also here, *can you imagine* is being used as a parenthetical aside.

> 2) And then... Can you imagine? I saw a monkey in this tree!

This is also fine. It is actually three sentences.

> 3) And then, can you imagine? I saw a monkey in this tree!

This, too, is fine—if interpreted as two sentences.

> 4) And then can you imagine I saw a monkey in this tree?

While acceptable, a more common punctuation of this variation would be to put a comma after *then*—and probably to add *that* after *imagine*. (However, that last change would be more than just a punctuation change. So, if you're looking purely for punctuation variations, this could be the least common of sentences as it is.)

---

Here are some other variations:

> And then (Can you imagine?) I saw a monkey in this tree!
>   And then—can you imagine?—I saw a monkey this tree!

As the other answer indicates, this is just a matter of choice.

---

If you want to consider some different phrases:

> Imagine it—I saw a monkey in this tree!
>   And then I saw a monkey in this tree! Can you believe it?
>   I can't believe it! I saw a monkey in this tree.

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation is context-dependent. In a personal letter you have the liberty to write:

> Could that have been the rare flying monkey???!!!

In a transcript of formal testimony before a senate subcommittee assessing the suitability of a candidate for the highest court in the land you might find just a single exclamation point and a single question mark:

> I liked beer. I still like beer, senator! Is it a crime to like beer?

or sometimes no exclamation point when the goal is to sound deadpan:

> I drank a lot of beer.

Comment: So what should I do here?

Comment: I would imagine, judging from the use of the word **you** in your sentence, that you're either writing a personal letter or a story. In either case, you are the Emperor of Punctuation.